# Sum from third row to last row in column B

Tags: excel, vba, sum, row

I have an error which prevents me to run properly my macro. When I try to run my macro, I have the error message `runtime error 1004 application defined or object defined error`

I checked my code, the error comes from this part of my code: `Range("K1") = "= SUM(" & thirdRow & "B:B" & LastRow & ")"`

It seems that the part “B:B” of this line is not properly recognized in my code. In fact, I would like my macro to return in cell K1 the value of the sum of my third cell in column B to my last cell in column B; in this case, 587,29 (please see screenshot enclosed I circled it in red).
Many thanks in advance.
Xavi[image]

```
Sub jfdjdgfjg()
  Dim i as Long, counter As Long
  Dim thirdcell As Range
  Dim r As Range
  Set r = ActiveCell
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim thirdRow As Long

  LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Range("B1").Activate

  For i = 2 To LastRow 'assuming a header row not to be counted
    If r.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then counter = counter + 1
      If counter = 2 Then
        Set thirdcell = r.Cells(i, "A")
        Exit For
      End If

  Next i

  Debug.Print thirdcell
  Debug.Print LastRow
  thirdRow = thirdcell.Row
  Debug.Print thirdRow
  Range("K1") = "= SUM(" & thirdRow & "B:B" & LastRow & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("K1").Formula = "= SUM("B" & thirdRow & ":B" & LastRow & ")"`

Comment: ^Scott beat me, the row goes behind the column designation if you are using that address style

Comment: thanks a lot Scott but when I insert the line your suggested me I have an error message: "compile error, syntax error"

Comment: Sorry: `Range("K1").Formula = "= SUM(B" & thirdRow & ":B" & LastRow & ")"`

Comment: thanks a lot, it works perfectly now!